# Group based on a category

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to group **Ms** based on **Id**. I would like to collapse the  **Id** to the specific **Ms** value. What is the best way to do this in R?

Below and example from the data that I am using:

```
      df<-structure(list(Ms = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Id = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
    1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 
    5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 
    6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 8, 
    9, 10, 8, 9, 10, 8, 9, 10, 8, 9, 10, 8, 9, 10, 8, 9, 10, 8, 9, 
    10, 8, 9, 10, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
    12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 14, 13, 14, 13, 14, 
    13, 14, 13, 14, 13, 14, 13, 14, 13, 14, 13, 14, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
    17, 15, 16, 17, 15, 16, 17, 15, 16, 17, 15, 16, 17, 15, 16, 17, 
    15, 16, 17, 15, 16, 17, 15, 16, 17, 15, 16, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
    18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
    20, 21, 20, 21, 20, 21, 20, 21, 20, 21, 20, 21, 20, 21, 20, 21, 
    20, 21, 20, 21, 22, 23, 22, 23, 22, 23, 22, 23, 22, 23, 22, 23, 
    22, 23, 22, 23, 22, 23, 22, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 
    24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 26, 27, 26, 27, 
    26, 27, 26, 27, 26, 27, 26, 27, 26, 27, 26, 27, 26, 27, 26, 27, 
    28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    29, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 31, 31, 
    31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 
    32, 32, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 34, 35, 34, 35, 
    34, 35, 34, 35, 34, 35, 34, 35, 34, 35, 34, 35, 34, 35, 34, 35, 
    36, 36, 36, 36, 36)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -355L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Ms = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Example of output:

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, is it not simply: `unique(df)` ?

Comment: @zx8754, basically instead of having 10 MS for 1 Id - I would like to have just one id with one MS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is one and only one Ms for a given ID, you could easily do this with the `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  summarize(Ms=max(Ms))
```

Output:

```
      Id    Ms
 * <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     0
 2     2     0
 3     3     0
 4     4     0
...
```